# Get new fileName as new1, new2 new3 and so on

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6

I have an array which contains the FileNames as New1, New2.... etc

I'm trying to code a function which returns me the new file name which is not present in the array and is the next consecutive number.

Let's say I have array as

`Let array = [{"Name" : "New"},{"Name" : "New1"},{"Name" : "New3"}]`

Then I want next new file name to be **New2**

How can I do this in java script?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You said: "the next consecutive number." The file names goes to New3. You then say "you want the new filename to be New2," What do you mean?

Comment: Use a while loop and generate new file name, try to find in your array, if not found, then the new file name is what you want.

Comment: Construct an array of the value in the `"Name"` key of each object in your array. Parse it so you only have the corresponding numbers, then go through that array and return the "next" number, if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below function you will be able to pass the default filename and file array both. So this function will work for any kind of filenames and find the missing number in between if there is any.

```js
function getNewFileName(FileArr, defaultName){
    let isKeepTrying = true;
    let fileName = defaultName;
    let defaultFileName = defaultName;
    let counter = 0;

    let namearr=  [];
    for(let i=0; i<FileArr.length ; i++ ){
        let newFileName = FileArr[i].Name;
        namearr.push(newFileName);
    }

    do{
        if(namearr.indexOf(fileName) > -1) {
            counter += 1;
            fileName = defaultFileName + counter;
            isKeepTrying = true;
        }
        else {
            isKeepTrying = false;
        }
    } while (isKeepTrying);
    return fileName;
};

var files = [{"Name": "New"}, {"Name":"New1"}, {"Name":"New3"}]

console.log(getNewFileName(files,"New"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should help you determine what is the number that is missing if you have a partially consecutive sequence. I've edited the sample array's objects so that the key is `name`, and not `"Name"`.

```js
let array = [{name: "New"},{name: "New1"},{name: "New3"}]

let nextNumber = (arr) => {
    return arr
        .map(o => o.name)
        .map(n => n.substring(3))
        .filter(s => s != "")
        .map(s => parseInt(s))
        .find((e, _i, a) => {
            if (!a.includes(e + 1))
                return true;
        }) + 1
}

console.log(nextNumber(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can create a substring and use `forEach` to loop the array .Then check the `index` with the substring

```js
let array = [{
  "Name": "New"
}, {
  "Name": "New1"
}, {
  "Name": "New3"
}];

array.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    if (item.Name.slice(3) !== '') {
      console.log("new" + index);
    }
  } else {
    if (item.Name.slice(3) != index) {
      console.log("new" + index);
    }
  }
})
```